# How to center text in li?

Tags: html, css, web, html-lists

I am trying to have equal spacing between four different `li` elements, but I end up with this:

[image]

HTML:

`<ul><li>Inbox</li></li><li>Drafts</li></li><li>Sent</li></li><li>Trash</li></ul>`

CSS:

```
ul li { 
     width: 25%;
     display: inline-block;
     text-align: center;
}
```

I have tested the CSS and it is working as it should. I think the problem is that the `li`'s don't all have the same amount of letters, so you end up with some weird visual effects. My reason for believing this:

[image]

(Equal spacing)

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vrudbLpb/1/) what you're looking for?

Comment: @Lucio Sure is! Can you post it in an answer with an explanation?

Comment: try using flexbox: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My approach with this issue is to center the li on the ul since the ul will naturally be the same width than the parent.

```
ul {
    /* Use flex boxes to align li items */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    /* Remove default padding from major browsers */
    padding: 0;
    /* Hide the default decorations for li items */
    list-style: none;
}
ul > li {
    /* Display the elements in one line */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Check out [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vrudbLpb/1/) to see it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ul {
    width:100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0
} 

li { 
     list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```