# jQuery slide menu appearing below main menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

With the code below I have created a fixed `<header>` consisting of an `<image>` and a `<navigation>`. Now I want to add sub-menus to the `<navigation>` as you can see in the `<button>` and `<SlideItem>` part.

The slide function works perfectly so far. However, it does appear right next to the main menu and not below it. It seems like that it stuck inside the `<li>` of the button.

What do I have to change in my code so the `sub-menus` appear below the main menu?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".SlideItem").slideDown(500);
  });
  $(".button").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".SlideItem").slideUp(500);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align:center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.navigation {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

ul {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align:center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.content{
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 10%; 
  margin-left: 10%; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}

.SlideItem {
  display: none;
}

.SlideItem {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"> 
  <div class="image">
  Image
  </div>
  <nav class="navigation"> 
    <ul>
      <li class="button"> 1.0 Main Menu 
        <ul class="SlideItem">
          <li> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
          <li> 1.2 Sub Menu </li>
          <li> 1.3 Sub Menu </li>     
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> 2.0 Main Menu </li>
      <li> 3.0 Main Menu </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

You can also find my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vu0hnqab/12/).

Comment: You can position the submenu absolute to get proportions out of that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` on `SlideItem` relative to immediate parent, and avoid to use css on elements directly e.g. you have used `ul { height: 100%;display:flex; ... }` it will apply css to all `ul` elements, better way is to use class or inheritance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".SlideItem").slideDown(500);
  });
  $(".button").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".SlideItem").slideUp(500);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.navigation {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.navigation > ul {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.navigation > ul > li {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}
.button{
  position:relative;
}
.SlideItem {
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: lime;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.SlideItem li{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">

  <div class="image">
    Image
  </div>

  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li class="button"> 1.0 Main Menu
        <ul class="SlideItem">
          <li> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
          <li> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
          <li> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> 2.0 Main Menu </li>
      <li> 3.0 Main Menu </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi Abhishek. Thanks for the answer. I also updated it here: https://jsfiddle.net/vu0hnqab/16/

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute`

```
.SlideItem {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}
```

You need to play around with your code as the mouse will loose focus on the main menu, causing the sub to slide up when hovering over it .

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set the display of your drop down element to `block`. This way the blocks will drop vertically below the parent menu item (and not next to it). Then remove the `height: 100%` it causes some issues with your drop down elements. Also, set the position to `absolute`, allowing you to decide it's vertical/horizontal position: here we have set it to `41px`.

Finally, I added a line of JS to ensure that the menu is hidden on page load.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".SlideItem").slideDown(500);
  });
  $(".button").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".SlideItem").slideUp(500);
  });
});

$(".button").children(".SlideItem").slideUp(0);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 43px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.navigation {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}

.SlideItem {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: lime;
  position: absolute;
  top: 41px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="header">

  <div class="image">
    Image
  </div>

  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li class="button"> 1.0 Main Menu
        <ul class="SlideItem">
          <li> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
          <li> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
          <li> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> 2.0 Main Menu </li>
      <li> 3.0 Main Menu </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute positioning on the submenu, with `position:relative` on the parent will keep the submenu positioned relative to the parent.

From there it's just a bit of extra twiddling; here I flipped the flex-direction of the submenu to vertical, and gave it a specific height. (Depending on the actual contents of these menus, this may or may not be necessary.)  The submenu is centered on the parent menu item because of the `justify-content` etc that's been globally applied to `li` items; if you want different styling for parent and child menus you may want to base those rules on classnames instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).children(".SlideItem").slideDown(500);
  });
  $(".button").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children(".SlideItem").slideUp(500);
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
}

.SlideItem {
  position: absolute;
  flex-direction: column; /* we already have display:flex below */
  height: 150px; /* height of full submenu */
}

.SlideItem li {
  flex-grow: 1 /* make all elements the same height */
}

/* Below is as in original code */
.header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.navigation {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

ul {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: red;
}

.SlideItem {
  display: none;
}

.SlideItem {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="image">
    Image
  </div>
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li class="button"> 1.0 Main Menu
        <ul class="SlideItem">
          <li> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
          <li> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
          <li> 1.1 Sub Menu </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> 2.0 Main Menu </li>
      <li> 3.0 Main Menu </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div>
```