# center align text inside navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following HTML, I am trying to center align the `span` tag inside `ul li`.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="../">
            </a>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <span>Need to Center align</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Its tricky. For other elements you could either go `text-center` or `mx-auto` but with `<li>`, you gotta hack it a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782973/text-align-center-in-li-element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [text-align center in <li> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782973/text-align-center-in-li-element)

Answer (score 1):

`<li class=“text-center”><span>...centered text</span></li>`

Answer (score 0):

If you add a class name to the `li`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" height=500, width= 400>
            </a>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="this">
                    <span>Need to Center align</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

You can then use CSS.

```
.this {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Check code pen https://codepen.io/Jsilvestri/pen/LJBRNp

Comment: I didnt see the users answer below as I answered. same answer... sorry